# Writing unhandled exceptions to file with winston@3

Tags: node.js, exception, winston

I'm trying to create a logger with winston@3 that handles unhandled exceptions in my Node.js application by logging the exception to the console and to a log file, but it is only being logged on the console.

```
const { path } = require('app-root-path');
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');

const unhandledExceptions = createLogger({
  exceptionHandlers: [
    new transports.File({
      filename: `${path}/logging/logs/exceptions.log`,
    }),
    new transports.Console()
  ],
  format: format.combine(
    format.label({ label: 'Unhandled exception' }),
    format.timestamp({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
    }),
    format.prettyPrint()
  )
});

throw new Error('wtf');
```

Any ideas on how I can get the exception written to the log file as well? Happy to provide more info.

Thanks in advance.